# Pandas average data with common value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Time (s) | Speed (m/s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 5 |
| 1.2 | 2 |
| 1.3 | 8 |
| ... | ... |
| 8.3 | 6 |
| 8.4 | 7 |
| 8.5 | 4 |

I would like to average the speed column across each second so that I get a dataframe like this:

| Time (s) | Speed (m/s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| ... | ... |
| 8 | 5.67 |

A rolling average doesn't seem to give me the result I want, and I'm quite new to pandas. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df["Time (s)"].astype(int))["Speed (m/s)"].mean().reset_index()

   Time (s)  Speed (m/s)
0         1     5.000000
1         8     5.666667
```

Comment: `astype(int)` is kind of awkward; fundamentally the time series should be a `Timedelta` and should not be downgraded away from that type. `resample` is a better fit.

Comment: @Reinderien nothing in the question suggests a specific type. If numeric, this is a fine solution.

Comment: @Reinderien - `astype(int)` wouldn't even work on a `Timedelta` object so there isn't any issue of "downgrading"

Comment: This works a treat thank you! I had tried using `groupby` before but I think there were issues with my syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is what `resample` is for. If you want the intervals to always start at round second values, one way is to insert a leading `NaN` at 1.0 seconds:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

speed = pd.Series(
    name='Speed (m/s)',
    data=[np.NaN, 5, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4],
    index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(
        name='Time (s)',
        data=[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5],
        unit='s',
    ),
)

print(speed, end='\n\n')
print(speed.resample(rule='1s').mean())
```

```
Time (s)
0 days 00:00:01           NaN
0 days 00:00:01.100000    5.0
0 days 00:00:01.200000    2.0
0 days 00:00:01.300000    8.0
0 days 00:00:08.300000    6.0
0 days 00:00:08.400000    7.0
0 days 00:00:08.500000    4.0
Name: Speed (m/s), dtype: float64

Time (s)
0 days 00:00:01    5.000000
0 days 00:00:02         NaN
0 days 00:00:03         NaN
0 days 00:00:04         NaN
0 days 00:00:05         NaN
0 days 00:00:06         NaN
0 days 00:00:07         NaN
0 days 00:00:08    5.666667
Freq: S, Name: Speed (m/s), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to truncate and group the seconds, then get the mean of each group, you can achieve that using [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time (s)': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5],
    'Speed (m/s)': [5, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4]
})

# Group by second and calculate mean speed for each second
mean_speed_df = df.groupby(df["Time (s)"].astype(int))["Speed (m/s)"].mean().reset_index()

print(mean_speed_df)
```

However, if you are trying to model speed as a function of time here, a more accurate approach would involve something like integration, spline fitting, or a moving average. If you're having trouble with moving average, I would suggest posting a question about that.

Comment: This code seems like... a slightly worse duplicate of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955411/313768). Don't `apply(lambda)` when `astype` is available.

Comment: Good call, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to pandas! Here's a step-by-step using common functions you'll find handy in your journey:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data like yours for testing purposes.
times = np.arange(1.0, 8.6, 0.1)                                                                        
speeds = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(times))                                                           
df = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                     
    "Time (s)": times,                                                                                  
    "Speed (m/s)": speeds                                                                               
})

# Create intervals by specifying ranges (bins) of values.                                               
intervals = pd.cut(df["Time (s)"],                                                                      
                   bins=pd.interval_range(start=times[0],                                               
                                          end=times[-1] + 1.0,                                          
                                          freq=1.0,                                                     
                                          closed='left'))

# Make new dataframe of average speed by interval by aggregating data.
averages = df.groupby(intervals).agg({"Speed (m/s)": 'mean'})

# Rename averages column (optional).
averages = averages.rename({"Speed (m/s)": "Average Speed (m/s)"}, axis='columns')

# Print final result.
print(averages)
```

Solutions involving timestamps, datetimes, and similar may be valid depending on how structured your data is. For this question, it appears that you only care about the numbers, so the solution I provide here suffices.